# How to scale up image where objects's size are remained same?

Tags: visio

If you have a file which include objects for example for EE like transistors, resistors etc and if you group them into one and then from the corner drag it to zoom in a bigger figure.
How can I make sure that these components are not zoom in only wiring changes?
The problem is that I have like 30 images with different sizes and I'm placing them in a table with many images side by side. However, if I keep the same scale then some images looks small compared to other. 
So I tried to scale them to get the same size. However, this make the components's sizes are also scaled up with different scale factors. 
Here is an example of circuit using the bult-in shapes in Visio. As you can see the components'sizes got bigger when I scaled up the object. This is usually desired. However, in my specific case I want to keep the component's size same.

Here is the Visio file or I think you can also use any available components in Visio.
https://file.io/VRUCR8yVgYxs

[image]

Comment: [Cross-post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=9922.msg45395;topicseen#msg45395)
Where you get all these shapes ? You want modify them via code ?

Comment: @Surrogate I did it intentionally. I have a Stencil and I want to modify it either code or manually but something which doesn't consume too much time. I